# JPA in Spring multiple 1:M mappings retrieve results in JpaSystemException

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

**SETUP**

Spring Boot 3.2.3, PostgreSql 15.x (duplicated issue with H2 so fairly certain not a DBMS issue)

JPA annotations relating 3 Entities  `SncEvent 1:M -> Sanctioned <- M:1 BoatClass`, i.e. a Many-to-Many with attributes on the join

SncEventDto defined as fields from all three classes `SncEvent.*, Sanctioned.sanctioned, BoatClass.id, BoatClass.className`

Integration test using @SpringBootTest and PostgresSql database

**ISSUE:**

Unable to retrieve the Many side of mapping using JpaRepository method `Optional<SncEventDto> findByVenue(String venue);`

error is `JpaSystemException: Cannot set field 'boats' to instantiate SncEventDto' field`

`SncEvent.boats` is defined as `private Set<Sanctioned> boats = new LinkedHashSet<>();`

Thanks for taking time to think about my problem!

JPA Entities follow:

SncEvent

```java
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "snc_event", schema = "public")
public class SncEvent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "snc_event_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "snc_event_seq", sequenceName = "snc_event_id_seq", initialValue = 10, allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "version")
    private Integer version;

    @Size(max = 50)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "event_name", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String eventName;

    @Size(max = 255)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "venue", nullable = false)
    private String venue;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sncEvent", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Sanctioned> boats = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    @Override
    public final boolean equals(Object o) {...} 

    @Override
    public final int hashCode() {...}
```

BoatClass

```java
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "boat_class", schema = "public", indexes = {
        @Index(name = "boat_class_business_key", columnList = "class_name", unique = true)
})
public class BoatClass {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "boat_class_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "boat_class_seq", sequenceName = "boat_class_id_seq", initialValue = 100, allocationSize = 10)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "version")
    private Integer version;

    @Size(max = 25)
    @Column(name = "class_name", length = 25)
    private String className;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "boatClass", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Sanctioned> events = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    @Override
    public final boolean equals(Object o) {...}

    @Override
    public final int hashCode() {...}
```

SanctionedId

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Embeddable
public class SanctionedId implements Serializable {
    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3056966086971282119L;
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "snc_event_id", nullable = false)
    private Long sncEventId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "boat_class_id", nullable = false)
    private Long boatClassId;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {...}

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
```

Sanctioned

```java
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "sanctioned", schema = "public")
public class Sanctioned {
    @EmbeddedId
    private SanctionedId id;

    @MapsId("sncEventId")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "snc_event_id", nullable = false)
    private SncEvent sncEvent;

    @MapsId("boatClassId")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "boat_class_id", nullable = false)
    private BoatClass boatClass;

    @Column(name = "sanctioned")
    private Boolean sanctioned;

    @Override
    public final boolean equals(Object o) {...}

    @Override
    public final int hashCode() {...}
}
```

SncEventDto

```java
public record SncEventDto(
        Long id,
        @NotNull @Size(max = 50) String eventName,
        @NotNull @Size(max = 255) String venue,
        Instant startTime,
        Instant endTime,
        Double registrationCost,
        @Size(max = 255) String registrationDeadline,
        Set<SanctionedDto> boats)
        implements Serializable {   }
```

SanctionedDto

```java
    public record SanctionedDto(
            Long boatClassId,
            String boatClassClassName,
            Boolean sanctioned) implements Serializable {       }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the call to the repository.  The test is green when I changed it to return the Entity rather than a DTO.

`Optional<SncEvent> findByVenue(String venue);` works while `Optional<SncEventDto> findByVenue(String venue);` does not work.